# Perl code doesn't run in a bash script with scheduling of crontab

Tags: bash, shell, perl, cron

I want to schedule my Perl code to be run every day at a specific time. so I put the below code in bash file:

```
Automate.sh

    #!/bin/sh
    perl /tmp/Taps/perl.pl
```

The schedule has been specified in below path:

```
10 17 * * * sh /tmp/Taps/Automate.sh > /tmp/Taps/result.log
```

When the time arrived to 17:10 the .sh file hasn't been running. however, when I run ./Automate.sh (manually) it is running and I see the result. I don't know what is the problem.

Perl Code

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;
use XML::Dumper;
use TAP3::Tap3edit;
$Data::Dumper::Indent=1;
$Data::Dumper::Useqq=1;
my $dump = new XML::Dumper;
use File::Basename;


my $perl='';
my $xml='';
my $tap3 = TAP3::Tap3edit->new();

   foreach my $file(glob '/tmp/Taps/X*')
   {
   $files= basename($file);
   $tap3->decode($files) || die $tap3->error;
    }

my $filename=$files.".xml\n";
$perl = $tap3->structure;
$dump->pl2xml($perl, $filename);
print "Done \n";
```

**error:**

```
No such file or directory for file X94 at /tmp/Taps/perl.pl line 22.
X94.xml
```

Comment: i did it but it is not running and i have an empty log file

Comment: @Saher : cron should send you the stderr by mail. Hence you should get some error messages. Alternatively, you could do a `2>&1` and collect the stderr inside your `result.log`. I would also use `-x` with `sh`. Then, the log file at least **can't be empty** anymore. And I would specify the full path to `sh` and `perl`.

Comment: Create crontab job where you put a command `env > /tmp/env_data` and once the cronjob is run you will see all variables set in crontab. `man crontab` gives sufficient information for understanding what required to set to run programs.

Comment: Why are you using basename? Consider what happens if your pwd is /

Comment: `$files` is not declared anywhere in the code you show. With `use strict`, this code would produce a fatal error `Global symbol "$files" requires explicit package`.

Comment: Also this code will only remember the last file name in the foreach loop. I'm not sure what the `decode` function does, if it stores all the files you read in it, but if it does not, then your code has some serious logical holes in it.

Comment: @TLP: I removed basement and it works fine.

Comment: @Saher Considering the other problems I have mentioned about your code, that seems unlikely. But yes, removing `basename` should avoid the fatal error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a lot of things that can go wrong here. The most obvious and certain one is that if you use a glob to find the file in directory "Taps", then remove the directory from the file name by using `basename`, then Perl cannot find the file. Not quite sure what you are trying to achieve there. The file names from the glob will be for example `Taps/Xfoo`, a relative path to the working directory. If you try to access `Xfoo` from the working directory, that file will not be found (or the wrong file will be found).

This should also (probably) lead to a fatal error, which should be reported in your error log. (Assuming that the `decode` function returns a false value upon error, which is not certain.) If no errors are reported in your error log, that is a sign the program does not run at all. Or it could be that `decode` does not return false on missing file, and the file is considered to be empty.

I assume that when you test the program, you `cd` to `/tmp` and run it, or your "Taps" directory is in your home directory. So you are making assumptions about where your program looks for the files. You should be certain where it looks for files, probably by using only absolute paths.

Another simple error might be that crontab does not have permission to execute the file, or no read access to "Taps".

Edit:

Other complications in your code:

- You include `Data::Dumper`, but never actually use that module.
- `$xml` variable is not used.
- `$files` variable not declared (this code would never run with `use strict`)
- Your `$files` variable is outside your `foreach` loop, which means it will only run once. Since you use `glob` I assumed you were reading more than one file, in which case this solution will probably not do what you want. It is also possible that you are using a `glob` because the file name can change, e.g. `X93`, `X94`, etc. In that case you will read the last file name returned by the glob. But this looks like a weak link in your logic.
- You add a newline `\n` to a file name, which is strange.

Comment: I tried to make relative changes and revise the code. But I got error as it shows above.

Comment: `No such file or directory` error is probably because you use `basename` on the relative file name, like I explained.

Answer (score 5):

`foreach my $file(glob 'Taps/X*')` -- when you're running from cron, your current directory is `/`. You'll want to provide the full path to that Taps directory. Also specify the output directory for Out.xml

Comment: I revised my code as above and now i get above error: No such file or directory for file X94 at /tmp/Taps/perl.pl line 22.
X94.xml

Answer (score 4):

Cron uses a minimal environment and a short `$PATH`, which may not necessarily include the expected path to `perl`. Try specifying this path fully. Or `source` your shell settings before running the script.

Comment: the specified file naming in crontab is not complete? I used short path but the result hasnt been changed!

Comment: I mean something like using /path/to/perl instead of just perl.

Comment: I revise my code and get above error. No such file or directory for file X94 at /tmp/Taps/perl.pl line 22.
X94.xml